# Laravel query builder where on eloquent relation

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables:

- users,
- jobs: id,user_id,name
- chats: id,job_id,name

I want to get chats depends on user's job. i've tried this one below, but i still get data from all chat, for example i want to get chat's data from user_id = 3:

```
$chat = Chat::with(['jobs' => function($query) use($userId){
                    $query->where('user_id',$userId);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a `chats()` relationship on the `User` model.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Get all the chats for the user.
     */
    public function chats()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Chat::class, Job::class);
    }
}
```

2. Get chat data from user_id = 3.

```php
$userId = 3;

User::query()->with(["chats"])->find($userId);
```

Resource: [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `whereHas` instead of `with`

[WhereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#clipText-78): Constraints your results based on the relationship query

```php
$chat = Chat::whereHas('jobs', function($query) use($userId){
                    $query->where('user_id',$userId);
})->get();
```

`With`: Load the giving relationship in the same query

you can use both to load the relationship and constraint the result:

```
$chat = Chat::with(['jobs'])
->whereHas('jobs', function($query) use($userId){
      $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Comment: got error: Error: Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array

Comment: @Hendra Sorry, I copy/paste that part of your code. The `whereHas` method takes 2 arguments, not an array: whereHas(`relationship name`, `function(){}`)